# an app need to connect a specific IP address with specific wifi, how can I do this from the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-wifi, private-network

i'm not really sure how to describe it, but generally it goes like this, there is an app that my company develop, because it still in development phase, this app need two thing so it can work:

1. configure a specific IP address from within the app itself to be able use internet (login, CRUD, etc)
2. use specific company hotspot

both prerequisite was quite easy with real phone, but due certain incident, currently I can only be able to use emulator for testing the app, and I'm not sure how to do it with emulator

Comment: The emulator uses a private network to talk to the host PC, which sends the actual request (because the emulator itself has no network access).  So if the machine you're running the emulator on is set up, the emulator should work.

Comment: ok, I will try it